# Configuring Web Deploy on Windows Server 2012

Tags: visual-studio, web-deployment, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to publish my web application on Visual Studio 2013 to a remote server operating on `Windows Server 2012 R2`. I have been following the steps [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later) to install Web Deploy.

I installed the `Recommended Server Configuration for Web Hosting Providers` and added the role "Management Services" for IIS 8 but I still couldn't find the `Deploy` option when right-clicking my website.

What could I possibly be missing?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that i had installed web deploy 3.6 on top of 3.5, removing 3.6 fixed the problem and now Deploy shows in the menu.